# Problem with Drawing real time chart through serial communication

Tags: c#, winforms

I [got an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HlDwVUR71yI) of how to draw live charts in C# winforms with serial data communication. I have few problems with it.

1. This code draws charts for only one data. My serial communication is coming from an Arduino where two figures of data are being written to serial with a tab distance between them, like "xxxx    yyyy". How do I draw both x and y to the live chart?
2. Everytime I close the application it hangs. I have to go in my desktop task manager to close it. How to solve this?
3. After few seconds the drawing of the chart becomes slow. Why is that? I need it to be able to fluently draw for at least 60 seconds.
4. The last line which is printed to Serial is a calculation result from the arduino microcontroller in the form of "aaaa    bbbb    cccc". I do not want this to be sent to the chart, I want this to be delivered to textboxes. How do I achieve this?
5. I would like the X-axis to be able to represent time in the form of ss:mmmm. I made some additions to the code from this [resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936346/time-on-x-axis-in-c-sharp-charts), but its not happening, I am getting the error "'CharValueType' does not exist in the current context". Whats wrong? Also the X-Axis is the expanding with time, it is frozen and the graphs just pass away through the left side when the space is filled. How to fix this?

Below is my complete code.

`

```
namespace Trial
{
    public partial class Form9 : Form
    {
        public Form9(string str_value)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.Text = str_value;
            this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "ss.fff";
            chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
            timer1.Start();
        }
        kayChart SerialDataChart;

        int i = 0;
        List<DateTime> TimeList = new List<DateTime>();




        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Clear();
                using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Caption like '%(COM%'"))
                {
                    var portnames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
                    var ports = searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().ToList().Select(p => p["Caption"].ToString());

                    var portList = portnames.Select(n => n + " - " + ports.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Contains(n))).ToList();

                    foreach (string s in portList)
                    {
                        comboBox1.Items.Add(s);
                        if (s.Contains("Arduino") == true)
                        {
                            int index = comboBox1.Items.IndexOf(s);
                            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = index;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
                        }

                    }

                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error E1!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PortOpening();
        }
        private void PortOpening()
        {
            try
            {
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
                {
                    serialPort1.Close();
                }

                string ComportDeviceID = comboBox1.Text.Split().First();
                serialPort1.PortName = ComportDeviceID;
                serialPort1.Open();

                


                if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
                {
                   
                    button1.Enabled = false;
                    button2.Enabled = true;
                    //to get date in textbox21
                    DateTime d = new DateTime();
                    d = DateTime.Now;
                    textBox1.Text = d.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
                    //code to get date ended, now starts code to open port.
                }


            } 
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Either hardware is disconnected or wrong port has been selected from drop down menu. " +
                "\n\nTry selecting correct option from drop down menu or reconnect the hardware." +
                "\n\nIf problem persists, restart the software.", "Error : Unable to connect to port.",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                PortClosing();

            }
            finally
            {
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
            }
        }

         private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PortClosing();
        }
        private void PortClosing()
        {
            try
            {
                serialPort1.Close();
            
                button1.Enabled = true;
                button2.Enabled = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }


        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
                {
                    serialPort1.BaudRate = 115200;
                    serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;
                    serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                    serialPort1.DataBits = 8;

                    serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SerialDataReceivedEventHandler);
                    //serialPort1.WriteLine("1");


                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error : Port needs to be open or wrong port selected!");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sData = sender as SerialPort;
            string recvData = sData.ReadLine();


            SerialData1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { SerialData1.AppendText("Received: " +recvData); });

            //initialization of chart update
            double data;
            bool result = Double.TryParse(recvData, out data);
            if(result)
            {
                SerialDataChart.TriggeredUpdate(data);
            }

        }

        private void Form9_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SerialDataChart = new kayChart(chart1, 60);
        
            SerialDataChart.serieName = "SerialRead";
        }

        private void Form9_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort1.Close();
            }
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void SerialData1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SerialData1.SelectionStart = SerialData1.Text.Length;
            SerialData1.ScrollToCaret();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            TimeList.Add(now);

            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(now, Math.Sin(i / 60.0));
            i += 2;
        }
    }
}
```

`

I tried the above quoted two samples but it did not work as expected.

Comment: _"but it did not work as expected"_ - so won't this question unless you add _how_ "it did not work". What did you expect? What happened instead? Did you get errors? If so: what were those? ... Also: There are 5 Questions. Which one do you want answered? Focus on one at a time.

Comment: Please boil this down to one question and only show code according to that one problem. Currently its more of the kind of "do a code review of my code and fix all the problems".

Comment: You are probably feeling overwhelmed, because you are trying to solve all at once. Don't. Divide and conquer. For example: _"This code draws charts for only one data. My serial communication is coming from an Arduino where two figures of data are being written to serial with a tab distance between them, like "xxxx yyyy". How do I draw both x and y to the live chart?"_ - why not make a mockup app with only a live chart and figure out how to draw to it? With hardcoded values if need be ...

Comment: 1: create two Series objects, perhaps.  2: it deadlocks on the Invoke() call, the port can't close until the DataReceived event completes.  Use BeginInvoke() or just don't bother calling Close().  3: too much data in the chart, typically, throw old data away.  4: have the Arduino tag the line of text so you can easily identify it, could be as simple as a single character at the start of the line.  5:  typo, it is ChartValueType with a t.  Ask only one question at SO.

Comment: You guys are right, will try to address each problem separately and post individual questions if problems persist.